# SQL to select the value of a column matching multiple values in another column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a `Chat_User` join table, and want to **retrieve the `ChatId` of `a`** between specified `UserId` of `x` and `y`.

`Chat_User` table:

```
Id  ChatId  UserId 
1   a       x   <===
2   b       z
3   a       y   <===
4   c       x
```

I tried:

```
SELECT ChatId
WHERE UserId IN ('x','y')
GROUP BY ChatId;
```

But it returns `ChatId` of `a` and `c`, but I only want `a`, as it has BOTH of my specified `UserId`(`x` and `y`).

Any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation offers one approach:

```sql
SELECT ChatId
FROM yourTable
WHERE UserId IN ('x', 'y')
GROUP BY ChatId
HAVING MIN(UserId) <> MAX(UserId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is starting only with one that you KNOW you want, and re-self-join to same table by that ID and the other user.  Make sure that there is an index on the table on (userid, chatid ) to help optimize the query.

```
select distinct
      YT.ChatID
   from
      YourTable YT
         JOIN YourTable YT2
            on YT2.UserID = 'y'
            AND YT.ChatID = YT2.ChatID
   where
      YT.userID = 'x'
```

This way, the outer WHERE clause is only ever considering those chats at a MINIMUM of one of the parties, so you are not even considering anyone else.  Only after those that have 'x' will it consider looking at the second instance for the 'y' user having the same chat.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I went with Tim's answer for its simplicity. But good to have this alternative in mind.

Comment: @Sean, ok, but then, what about a 3 or 4 way chat going on?  It will get more complicated... just consider for future, glad you have AN answer that works for you.